# Does the Object.wait() method reacquire the monitor when it throws an exception?

Tags: java, exception, synchronization, signals, wait

The Java documentation I'm using makes it clear that the `Object.wait()` method reqcquires the associated monitor before it returns, regardless of whether it was notified or is a spurious wakeup; any normal method return will be preceeded by a monitor reacquisition.

However, it's a little less clear about what will happen in the event `Object.wait()` throws an exception, e.g., an `Interrupted Exception`. I'm inferring that it does indeed reacquire the lock before throwing an exception. However, the documentation isn't very explicit about it, so I'm not 100% sure...

Here is the documentaiton I'm looking at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29

So, is my inference correct, or does my calling code need to address the monitor state (e.g., reacquiring it if necessary) after an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1) specifies this in much more detail than `Object#wait`'s Javadoc. According to that text, the lock must be unconditionally reacquired. Quoting the relevant bits:

> 1. Thread *t* is added to the wait set of object *m*, and performs *n* unlock actions on *m*.
> 2. Thread *t* does not execute any further instructions until it has been removed from *m*'s wait set. The thread may be removed from the wait set due to any one of the following actions, and will resume sometime afterward:
>
>    - [...]
>    - An interrupt action being performed on *t*.
> 3. Thread *t* performs *n* lock actions on *m*.

Comment: Empirically, this appears to be correct. It is also reasonable. I am not sure it can be deduced from the documentation, which suggests a documentation bug.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I have completely rewritten the answer: the JLS in fact specifies quite clearly that the lock will be unconditionally reacquired.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks, that does explain it very clearly. Thanks for the JLS link as well... I'll use it next time I have a similar question that the API docs don't address.  :)